# How to optimize cURL request to an API?

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am writing an API for an application, which will be hosted on the Cloud, so that the User's can access it through there unique Application ID's. For the time being it is working all fine and giving User's desired results. Now suddenly the question in which I have stuck is, how to handle multiple request at a time. I need some suggestions through which I can handle multiple requests to the API. Is there a way that I can optimize my code for some fast results to the User. Should I cache the common request of the User's so that I can directly give output to the User from Cached data. Or should I save the latest requested data in database and use indexing to give a fast Output to the User.
Please give suggestions, that I can write a good and fast application and for long run.

Answer (score 0):

**Profile your code** using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) or [xhprof](http://mirror.facebook.net/facebook/xhprof/doc.html).

**Identify bottlenecks** using real-life evidence, then eliminate or minimize the bottlenecks.

**Don't blindly begin caching data** under the assumption that it is a performance problem.